# Search in datagrid using combo box

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have to search data from the text box in datagrid using c#
My code is

```
          private void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        //DataSet ds15 = new DataSet();

  DataTable dt= new DataTable();                        

 SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ColumName from TableName where Field like '%{0}%'", comboBox_Search.Text); 
  adpt.Fill(dt);//datatable to catch the fields from the database
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Getting error Arguement exception was unhandled

I want to search through combo box

Comment: columnname and Table are actual columns of your atm_status ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no  constructor match your parameters on [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)

```
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("Select ColumName from TableName where Field like '%{0}%'", 
                 comboBox_Search.Text), sqlcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Query every time to the database is not a preferable approach. Instead take a `BindingSource` object and fill the source once. Then use `BindingSource.Filter` property to get relevant result set and bind the result set to grid.

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) and and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) link.

Also, to fix your issue you can try like this:

```
....
sqlcon.Open();
string query  = string.Format("Select ColumName from TableName where Field like '%{0}%'", comboBox_Search.Text);
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
adpt.Fill(dt);//datatable to catch the fields from the database
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

How does the SqlDataAdapter know where to get the result from?

You are not initializing the constructor for your SqlDataAdapter properly. The first argument is the full select statement and the second argument is your connection string.

```
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("Select ColumName from atm_status where Table like '%{0}%'", comboBox_Search.Text), sqlcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txt_Searchque_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connector_string = "datasource = localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;";
    MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(connector_string);
    sqlcon.Open();
    string query = string.Format("Select * from oep.quiz where que like '%{0}%'", txt_Searchque.Text);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
    MySqlDataAdapter adpt = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adpt.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```